# Android - activity2 back to activity1 fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `List` view (I have used `Recycler` view ) which is in `activity1` > `fragment2`

from here user click on a row and go to `activity2` to show the content

Now when user click on back button it should take user to `activity1` `fragment2`.

How should I implement it on `activity2.onBackPressed()`?

Answer (score 0):

Calling [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) will finish the current activity and return the user to whatever is on top of the activity back stack. In your case it will be `activity1`.

The default implementation (below) of `onBackPressed()` already calls `finish()` so you should not even have to override it.

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!mFragments.popBackStackImmediate()) {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By mistake I did this in my first `activity`

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Job job) {
    startActivity(MyActivity.createIntent(this, Model));
    finish() // this was creating problem
}
```

I removed the `finish()` method and everything is now working perfectly!